# Sufficient Condition for Spectral radius to be greater than or equal to 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a square matrix with non-negative entries and $v$ be a non-negative vector such that $Tv \geq v$ (basically the inequality holds for each entry i.e., $(Tv)_j \geq v_j)$. Can we conclude that the spectral radius of $T$ is greater than or equal to 1 ?

Comment: Are you saying the inequality holds for _any_ nonnegative vector $v$?

Comment: It holds for some vector $v,$ not necessarily for all vectors.

Comment: A dumb counterexample is $T$ being the zero matrix and $v = 0$. I feel there are also some other counterexamples where $v \ne 0$.

Comment: $v \neq 0.$ Is there a simple counterexample for non-zero $v$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is true, it comes with the Perron-Frobenius Theorem and the Collatz–Wielandt Formula. The fact can be found [here](https://www.lakeheadu.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/77/Baldin.pdf) in **Theorem III.2**, part *(iii)*, stated as follows:

> Let $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a square matrix with
> non-negative entries and let $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a
> set of all non-negative vectors (excluding the zero vector). Then
>
> $$ \max_{v \in \mathcal{P}}  \underset{v_j \ne 0}{\min_{1\le j \le n}}
> \frac{(Tv)_j}{v_j} = \text{the spectral radius of}\; T. $$

Comment: I think you mean $j$ instead of $i$ in your equation.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Fixed, thank you.